# Configuring the SP Farm: The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are not registered

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, 2016, installation

I logged in my Windows Server 2012 R2 with the account svc_install which has administrators permissions as it belongs in the administrators group.

I installed the prerequisites and ran the setup for SharePoint 2016 server. 
I did not run the SharePoint configuration wizard as I wanted to install the rest of sharepoint using powershell.

I started by adding `Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` then I got the error: `The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are not registered.`

OK, so I tried to use `Add-SPShellAdmin -UserName contoso\svc_install` then I got the following error:

```
Add-SPShellAdmin : Cannot access the local farm. Verify that the local farm is properly configured, currently available, and that you have the appropriate permissions to access the database before trying again.
```

Why on earth can't it just run normally but all this fuss? By the way, I have `opened/ran the powershell console as administrator`.

NOTE: at this moment there are no SharePoint databases created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behaviour, as you have not created farm yet. Once configuration database created then this message will go away for this account.

Simply, open SharePoint PowerShell and run the new spconfigurationdatabase command to create farm.

A good reference to script: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/12/create-sharepoint-2016-farm-using-powershell.html

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the @waqas answers, Please open the console using the account which is farm administrator and also its local Administrator on the machine from where it's getting accessed.
This resolved in my case.